# Sonata Formatter and Sonata Admin Integration with Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to add a formatter inside my administration.

I installed `SonataAdminBundle` (works fine) and `SonataFormatterBundle`.

Here is *(a part of)* my config.yml

```
sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]

sonata_formatter:
    default_formatter: text
    formatters:
        markdown:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.markdown
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig #keep this commented unless you are using media bundle.
        text:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.text
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
        rawhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
        richhtml:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.raw
            extensions:
                - sonata.formatter.twig.control_flow
                - sonata.formatter.twig.gist
                - sonata.media.formatter.twig
        twig:
            service: sonata.formatter.text.twigengine
            extensions: [] # Twig formatter cannot have extensions
    ckeditor:
        templates:
            browser: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:browser.html.twig'
            upload: 'SonataFormatterBundle:Ckeditor:upload.html.twig'

ivory_ck_editor:
    configs:
        default:
            language:  '%locale%'
            toolbar: standard

sonata_admin:
    templates:
        # default global templates
        layout:  SonataAdminBundle::layout.html.twig
```

In the official documentation, it is asked to add a `layout.html.twig` in `app/Resources/SonataAdminBundle/views/`. In Symfony 3, there is no path like that, so I created it.

In ArticleAdmin.php, I added

`->add('preview', 'sonata_simple_formatter_type', array('format' => 'richhtml', 'attr' => array('class' => 'ckeditor')))`

I also tried

```
->add('preview', 'sonata_simple_formatter_type', array(
                    'format' => 'richhtml',
                    'ckeditor_context' => 'default', // optional
                ))
```

But it has no effect, there is no formatter in my preview field.

I noted that the 'new' `layout.html.twig` refers to `bundles/sonataformatter/...` and `bundles/ivoryckeditor/...` files but there is no `ivoryckeditor` or `sonataformatter` included in `web/bundles/`.

Maybe it is a version problem. So, here is the "require" part of my composer.json :

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.20",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.2",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.2",
        "sonata-project/google-authenticator": "^1.0",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.6",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2.2",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.3.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you installed assets after installing the bundle? 
   I mean Symfony console command `bin/console assets:install`
2. I don't know for sure, which layout.html.twig you speaking about, But it might be standard_layout.html. This layout you have to add in your AppBundle (If you haven't overwritten the SonataBundle). 
   In my case path to layout is: `AppBundle/Resources/views/Admin/standard_layout.html.twig`.
   And in your `config.yml` you have to substitute standart sonata layout with your one:

   ```
   sonata_admin:
   title: 'Yor title'
   templates:
        ## ...
        layout: 'AppBundle::Admin/standard_layout.html.twig'
        ## ...
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Installing assets works for me.

Comment: Don't forget always use two commands:

`bin/console assets:install` - after installing the bundles.

`bin/console cache:clear`   - every time you have any problem.
It will save a lot of time for you.